# How to add milliseconds consecutively (with condition) to dates in R?

Tags: r

I am a newbie at R so I'm not very sure if this question has been answered before. (Also my first time asking a question here, not sure if I have adhered to the correct format.)

Basically I want to add 10 milliseconds consecutively to every unique time stamp in my data.

What my data looks like:

```
17:30:20.12
17:30:20.12
17:30:20.12
17:30:20.12
17:30:20.12
17:30:20.12
17:31:21.48
17:31:21.48
17:31:21.48
17:31:21.48
17:31:21.48
17:31:21.48
```

What I want it to look like:

```
17:30:20.12
17:30:20.13
17:30:20.14
17:30:20.15
17:30:20.16
17:30:20.17
17:31:21.48
17:31:21.49
17:31:21.50
17:31:21.51
17:31:21.52
17:31:21.53
```

Is this possible in R? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, very much possible.

Just create the vector of additions, ie N times 0.1 sec, and add it to your time column.  Simplified:

```
R> now <- Sys.time()
R> now                 # I have options("digits.secs"=6)
[1] "2016-11-16 21:37:55.502532 CST"
R> now <- trunc(now)   # truncate to 'round' secondss
R> addThis <- 0.010001 * 0:4   # need some fudge for display
R> now + addThis
[1] "2016-11-16 21:37:55.000000 CST" "2016-11-16 21:37:55.010000 CST"
[3] "2016-11-16 21:37:55.020001 CST" "2016-11-16 21:37:55.030003 CST"
[5] "2016-11-16 21:37:55.040004 CST"
R>
```

The imprecision in doubles gets to us here, so we can't use `0.01 * 0:4` but add a little 'fluff'.  In your real application you can adjust as needed.

The condition about uniqueness can be added with standard vector operation tricks, ie computes difference and test for different from zero.  You can then cumsum that to get the sequence etc pp.

Comment: Hi! Thank you, the adding of milliseconds is working. However, is there any other way to go about using 0.010001 * 0:4? The number of observations in each group of timestamps is different. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Yes, that was an illustration for an increment vector. See my last paragraph.  That part you need to work out.  We don't your sample table.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is a column in a data.frame, I like `data.table` for this.

First, I read your data into a data.frame with `read.table()`. Then, set the timestamp to a new column (`V2`) as `POSIXct` class by adding an arbitrary day first (not sure if there is such a thing as time without a date in R...). Then set the `data.frame` as a `data.table`

```
    library(data.table)
    x$V2 <- as.POSIXct(paste("2016-11-16", x$V1))
    setDT(x)
    x[, V3 := V2 + (0:.N)/10, by=V2]
```

Finally, using the `data.table` syntax to set a new column by reference, we can get a vector from 0 to `.N` ( `.N` being the length of each group of the observations with the same value in the column specified in `by=`, in this case `V2`). Then we divide that vector by 10 to get milliseconds, starting at 0, and add it to the original times in column V2.